# Speed up image animations with jQuery for iPad optimization

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, web-applications

I'm wondering how could I speed up the movement of images in a site. This site should be as fast as possible for the iPad and currently the movement of images is not very fluid. (tested on iPad3 as well as on iPhone 5)

The site is very simple. Mainly the structure is this:

```
<div id="slide1" class="slides">
</div>

<div id="slide2" class="slides">
</div>

<div id="slide3" class="slides">
</div>

...  //around 20 slides
```

Each slide has a background image (which is the current slide). Something like this:

```
#slide4{
    background: url(../img/ipad/Slide4.PNG) no-repeat;
    z-index:103;  //over the previous slide
    margin-left:-2000px;  //in order to animate it later
}
```

And to go from one slide (image) to another, I'm using jQuery in this way:

```
    //from slide3 to slide4 with animation
$('#slide3').click(function(){
    $('#slide4').show();
    $('#slide4').animate({'margin-left' : '0'});
});
```

I have already tried reducing the weight of the images but sometimes i can not reduce it more without a considerable quality lose.

I have thought also about the possibility of loading the images dynamically using AJAX but there's not enough time to load the next slide before it is rendered as the movement is quite fast.

What would you recommend me? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the iPad/iPhone, use CSS3 animations/transitions, not jQuery animations for best/smoothest performance.  CSS3 animations/transitions are implemented in native browser code and aren't subjected to the single-threadedness of javascript and can sometimes more smoothly run in the background while doing other things.

If you're not familiar with these CSS3 features, here's a site where you can start: http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/ (see the tutorial).